How to provide additional information on enum values to an LLM in LangChain
I'm trying to extract structured information with an LLM say GPT-4 using LangChain in python. My goal is to classify companies by associating them with tags.
My output class is of the type:
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel

class Company(BaseModel):
    industry: list[Industry]
    customer: list[Customer]

So far so good. Now the problem is, some of the tags might be somewhat specific and I'd like to pass more information to the LLM to help it decide between options. Using Enum from aenum as described here I can add e.g. docstrings to the enum values:
from aenum import Enum

class Industry(Enum):
    _init_ = 'value __doc__'
    it = "Information Technology", "All kinds of computer stuff"
    agriculture = "Agriculture", "Farming, irrigation, fertilizers etc."

class Customer(Enum):
    _init_ = 'value __doc__'
    B2C = "B2C", "Companies selling directly to consumers"
    B2B = "B2B", "Companies selling to other businesses"

Now I have my values and some helpful explanations, however, there's no direct way of passing these to the LLM.
If I use the .with_structured_output() or PydanticOutputParser they fail to pass the docstrings from the enum members:
from langchain_core.output_parsers import PydanticOutputParser

parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=Company)

parser.get_format_instructions()
# 'The output should be formatted as a JSON instance that conforms to the JSON schema below.
# As an example, for the schema {"properties": {"foo": {"title": "Foo", "description": "a list of strings", "type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}}}, "required": ["foo"]}
# the object {"foo": ["bar", "baz"]} is a well-formatted instance of the schema. The object {"properties": {"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}} is not well-formatted.
# Here is the output schema:
# ```
# {"properties": {"industry": {"type": "array", "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Industry"}}, "customer": {"type": "array", "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/Customer"}}}, "required": ["industry", "customer"], "definitions": {"Industry": {"title": "Industry", "description": "An enumeration.", "enum": ["Information Technology", "Agriculture"]}, "Customer": {"title": "Customer", "description": "An enumeration.", "enum": ["B2C", "B2B"]}}}
#```'

As a workaround, I can of course write a custom prompt that explicitly details the docstrings, but was just curious if anyone has figured out a more straightforward way to do it.

You could do add a field to __get_pydantic_json_schema__ method (and use pydantic v2), like this:
from aenum import Enum
from pydantic.json_schema import GetJsonSchemaHandler
from pydantic_core import core_schema

class EnumSchemaDoc(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(cls, core_schema: core_schema.CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler):
        schema = handler(core_schema)
        schema['documentation'] = {e.value : e.__doc__ for e in cls}
        return schema

class Industry(EnumSchemaDoc):
    _init_ = 'value __doc__'
    it = "Information Technology", "All kinds of computer stuff"
    agriculture = "Agriculture", "Farming, irrigation, fertilizers etc."

class Customer(EnumSchemaDoc):
    _init_ = 'value __doc__'
    B2C = "B2C", "Companies selling directly to consumers"
    B2B = "B2B", "Companies selling to other businesses"


from langchain_core.output_parsers import PydanticOutputParser
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Company(BaseModel):
    industry: Industry
    customer: Customer

parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=Company)

parser.get_format_instructions()

'The output should be formatted as a JSON instance that conforms to the JSON schema below.\n\nAs an example, for the schema {"properties": {"foo": {"title": "Foo", "description": "a list of strings", "type": "array", "items": {"type": "string"}}}, "required": ["foo"]}\nthe object {"foo": ["bar", "baz"]} is a well-formatted instance of the schema. The object {"properties": {"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}} is not well-formatted.\n\nHere is the output schema:\n```\n{"$defs": {"Customer": {"documentation": {"B2B": "Companies selling to other businesses", "B2C": "Companies selling directly to consumers"}, "enum": ["B2C", "B2B"], "title": "Customer", "type": "string"}, "Industry": {"documentation": {"Agriculture": "Farming, irrigation, fertilizers etc.", "Information Technology": "All kinds of computer stuff"}, "enum": ["Information Technology", "Agriculture"], "title": "Industry", "type": "string"}}, "properties": {"industry": {"$ref": "#/$defs/Industry"}, "customer": {"$ref": "#/$defs/Customer"}}, "required": ["industry", "customer"]}\n```'

